# Why can psql commands not be executed from PGAdmin "Query Editor"

Tags: psql, pgadmin

From the PGAdmin "Query Editor" I have tried, in the spirit of [this SE post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959/how-do-you-use-script-variables-in-psql), to embed psql commands in my SQL scripts: For instance,

```
\set myTempVariable 42; 
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE age= :'myTempVariable';
```

This attempt at executing hybrid SQL/psql code failed. Why does the "Query Editor" executor not, by default, accept psql commands?  Is there a way this can be achieved?

(Note that I have [found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316773/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-named-constant-in-a-postgresql-query) to the above functionality using `WITH ...` but I specifically want to understand what the restrictions are on PGAdmin queries and why)

Comment: Because `psql` commands - as the name implies - are only understood by `psql`. Those are not [SQL commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html)  understood by the server.